# IE 8/9 issue with JWPlayer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mootools, internet-explorer-9, jwplayer

I have this lightbox which plays a video perfectly for safari/chrome/ffox but not ie8/ie9

```
            var preload = jwplayer('mb_inline_0_-1').setup({
                        'flashplayer': '/scripts/jwplayer/player.swf',
                        'file': 'test.mov',
                        'streamer': 'rtmp://etc.mysite.com.au/cfx/st',
                        'controlbar': 'bottom',
                        'width': '470',
                        'height': '290'
                    });
```

The error I see when using developer tools in IE console is "LOG: No suitable players found " which leads me to believe there is some compatibility between the content type and IE. I've looked high and low for info about this but no luck so far.

Resolved: Bit of a dumb move.. the flash plugin wasn't installed in ie8

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution! I just had the same dumb move and hadn't even thought of checking if flash is installed!

Answer (score 2):

IE 9 also supports html5 player, so you can simply provide another mode, e.g.:

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
    'modes': [
        {type: 'html5'},
        {type: 'flash', src: 'js/player/player.swf'}
    ],
    'id':'player',
    'width':'300',
    'height':'20',
    'controlbar':'bottom'
});
```